# C# OpenCvSharp extension

Tags: c#, opencv

I'm having this issue

```
The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'OpenCvSharp' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

on this line:

```
 Bitmap bmp = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(image);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I believe you're missing the Extensions package from Nuget : OpenCvSharp4.Extensions

Comment: It's enable, check    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ss0XoiTytE4EahbgsIJ1iNlg-YsaSZn2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try installing this one : https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp4.Extensions